# Pexpect does not get the output correctly

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I'm using Pexpect to interact with a remote firewall. Everything in the interaction is okay but, when I try to get the output with child.before, I do not get what I want. This is my code:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh admin@X.X.X.X')
child.sendline(password)
child.expect('>')
child.sendline('set cli pager off')
child.expect('>')
child.send('show system info')
child.expect('>')
child.before
```

The output I get in child.before sentence is next:

> ' set cli \r\x1b[Kadmin@name(active)'

In the firewall side, this is the interaction I'm receiving (It is copied directly  from child.interact()):

```
admin@ctsmefw1(active)> set cli pager off
admin@ctsmefw1(active)> show system info

hostname: name
ip-address: ip
# ...There are more lines but these are omitted here...

admin@name(active)>
```

So the interaction with the firewall is correct. Why I can'nt get the output? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help, regards

Mike

Comment: Since you are connecting using `ssh` directly, have you considered using [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) rather than expect? It will be faster and you won't have to worry about terminal issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `child.send('show system info')` to `child.sendline('show system info')`.